# datatool package: wishing for keys / column names with special characters, can't get it to work

Tags: accents, datatool

I wish to read a CSV file that has special characters in the headers. While I got what the [documentation](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) says about special characters in the body of the file, I couldn't get it to work for the column headers.

For example the file `foobar.csv` containing

```
cliché, foo
10,20
```

Can't be read by `\DTLloaddb{foobar.csv}`, though, presenting the following error message

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. \DTLloaddb{foobar}{foobar.csv}
```

While the same file exchanging `cliché` for `cliche` compiles flawlessly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**Minimum working example:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample}
cliché
10
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{sample}{sample}
\begin{document}
\DTLdisplaydb{sample}
\end{document}
```

Won't work with `cliché`, does work with `cliche`.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal working example, beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`? For the csv you might use `filecontents`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without specifying any `<options>`, both the header text and the key associated with that field/column is given the name in the header, and you can't have `\cliché` as the header key. So, specify a separate set of `keys` for the header:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents,datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.csv}
cliché, foo
10,20
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[keys={cliche,foo}]{foo}{foo.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLdisplaydb{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is super helpful. Thank you very much!